# Unique the columns and get the frequencies in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unique

I have a `data.txt` with a matrix structure (4 X 9):

```
101000110
000000010
001010010
100101101
```

I want to count the frequencies of unique columns, the expected result is:

```
1001 2
0000 1
1010 1
0001 3 
0010 1
1110 1
```

I only find "unique lines according to specific columns" using `awk` on the Internet, do I need to first transpose my data to solve this problem. I wonder whether there is a more direct way to figure it out? Thank you.

Comment: How are the columns defined?

Comment: @OlafDietsche The first column is 1001, the second column is 0000, the third is 1010,...... There are 9 columns in the `data.txt` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` will help:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
         a[i]=a[i]""$i
       }
     }
     END{
     for (i=1;i<=9;i++) {
       res[a[i]]++
       }
     for (r in res){
         print r, res[r] 
       }
     }' FS= yourfile
```

**Result**

```
1110 1
0000 1
0010 1
0001 3
1010 1
1001 2
```

**Explanation**

```
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
         a[i]=a[i]""$i
       }
     }
```

Stores the info in a nine column array as a key, as we know that it’s a regular matrix we will append each value to its position

```
 for (i=1;i<=9;i++) {
   res[a[i]]++
   }
```

Store the number into an associative array and count the occurrences

```
 for (r in res){
     print r, res[r] 
   }
```

Just show the  final result.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to transpose it. Use `awk` to split on empty field separator and append each value in an array indexed by column number. In the `END` block count the frequency and print it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      a[i] = a[i] $i
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=length(a); i++)
      freq[a[i]]++

   for(i in freq)
      print i, freq[i]
}' file

0000 1
0010 1
0001 3
1001 2
1010 1
1110 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -aF// -lne '$s[$_] .= $F[$_] for 0 .. $#F;
                 }{
                 $c{$_}++ for @s;
                 print "$_\t$c{$_}" for keys %c' < data.txt
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` handles the newlines
- `aF//` split each line by characters to the @F array
- @s accumulates characters from particular columns
- At the end, the hash table %c is used to count the frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

although not needed, here is a tranpose and count solution with unix toolset.

```
$ sed 's/./&\n/g' file | 
  sed '/^$/d'          | 
  pr -4ts' '           | 
  tr -d ' '            | 
  sort                 | 
  uniq -c              | 
  awk '{print $2,$1}'

0000 1
0001 3
0010 1
1001 2
1010 1
1110 1
```