# Loop every three consecutive rows in linux

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I have a file `hundred.txt` containing 100 rows.

For example:

```
1 0 0 1
1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0
....
1 0 0 1
```

I need to manipulate some calculations within every 3 consecutive rows, for instance, I need to use the Row1-Row3 first to do my calculation:

```
1 0 0 1
1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
```

then the Row2-Row4:

```
1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0
```

...... the Row98-Row100.

Each output will generate a file (e.g. Row1.txt, Row2.txt,... Row98.txt), How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Just curious. Why bash for this?

Comment: @mascoj Because I need to calculate something within every 3 consecutive rows. Actually, the thing I want to calculate is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835689/unique-the-columns-and-get-the-frequencies-in-linux. In that question, I used 4 rows, but now I have 100 rows, every 3 consecutive rows must get a result as that question.

Comment: I meant more as to why restrict yourself to bash. There are plenty of scripting languages in which this would be an extremely simple task.

Comment: Yes, use a language with libraries for handling binary matrices…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR>2{printf "%s", a2 ORS a1 ORS $0 ORS > FILENAME"."(++c)}
           {a2=a1;a1=$0}' file
```

for the input file

```
$ cat file
1 0 0 1
1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0
```

generates these 3

```
$ head file.{1..3}
==> file.1 <==
1 0 0 1
1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0

==> file.2 <==
1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0

==> file.3 <==
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0
```

you can embed your computation is the script and output only the results but you didn't provide any details on that.

**Explanation**

> `NR>2` starting third row
> `printf ...` start printing last 3 rows
> `> FILENAME"."(++c)` to a file derived from input filename with counter suffix
>
> `a2=a1;a1=$0` update last two rows

if your rolling window is small `n` you can scale this script by changing `NR>(n-1)` and keeping track of last rows in `a(n-1)...a1` and printing accordingly.  If `n` is large, better to use a array (or better a circular array).

This is perhaps the most generic version...

```
$ awk -v n=3 'NR>n-1{fn=FILENAME"."c; 
                     for(i=c+1;i<c+n;i++) printf "%s\n", a[(i-n)%n] > fn;
                     print > fn} 
                    {a[(c++)%n]=$0}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

`bash` isn't a great choice for data processing tasks, but it is possible (albeit slow):

```
{ read row1
  read row2
  count=0
  while read row3; do
    # Do something with rows 1-3
    { echo $row1 $row2 $row3; } > Row$((count+=1)).txt
    # Slide the window
    row1=$row2
    row2=$row3
  done
} < hundred.txt
```

Comment: I'm a beginner of Linux, so I can only think out the `bash` method, could you help me with other quick solutions (other than `bash`) to this problem, thank you. Say, I have 1 X 10^10 rows or more.

Answer (score 2):

One hundred rows of four binary-valued columns is not too much; just read it all in at once.

```
mapfile -t rows < inputfile
for r in "${!rows[@]}"; do # loop by row index
    (( r >= 2 )) || continue
    # process "${rows[r-2]}" "${rows[r-1]}" and "${rows[r]}"
    # into file Row$((r-1))
done
```

If the quantity of data grows significantly, you really want to use a better tool, such as Python+numpy (because your data looks like binary matrices).